# Lipschitz function are proper map

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions, proper-maps

> Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, $(1 \leq n \leq m)$ be a injective Lipschitz function, it is true that $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for all compact $K \subset \mathbb R^m$, i.e $f$ is a proper map.

I'm interested to know if that fact is true, I try to found some counterexamples but I can't found it, any hint or suggestions I will be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example $\text{arctan}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Clearly the preimage of $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is $\mathbb{R}$. The statement is more interesting if you restrict the codomain to the image of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Only one question why is more interesting if restring of the codomain? Is for in these restriction $f$ is a bijection?

Comment: @NickWeber If we restring the codomain to the image of $f$ this counterexample doesn't work anymore because the image is $(-\pi /2, \pi /2)$ and it's not compact. Yes in this case $f$ is bijective.